# SwiftyJSON dictionary parsing

Tags: ios, json, swifty-json

I am attempting to use SwiftyJSON to parse some data from a server.

For example, say the JSON returned from the server is:

```
{     
 "data":{  
     "id":"92",
     "name":"harry",
     "username":"Hazza"
   },
 "error":false
}
```

I would like to get the username string and so to do this I obtain the data object using:

```
let data = json["data"].dictionaryValue
```

Then in order to grab the username string I would expect to be able to do

```
let username = data["username"].stringValue
```

However this returns an error saying '(String, JSON) does not have a member named '.stringValue'.

Where am I going wrong with this seemingly simple problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you should do is:

```
if let username = json["data"]["username"].string {
    println(username)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, according to the README.md, under  non-optional getter, there does seem to be a use for stringValue.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#non-optional-getter

Answer (score 3):

While the above will work, The real issue was you needed to unpack the dict value:

`let username = data["username"]!.stringValue`

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3/4

```
guard let username = json["data"]["username"].string else { return nil }
```